# Android webview only zoom in

Tags: android, webview

i have a html output, wich is full screen at the start. With the zoom control i can zoom in/out.

I want only zoom in, and not out. So: the minimal zoom out i want is 100% of the full screen. 
And the maximal zoom in i want to 400%.

Is there a way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing it the hard way, I would suggest to

- disable the built-in zoom controls via WebSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false)
- add your own zoom control buttons on top of the WebView using FrameLayout

Answer (score 3):

If you can modify the html you display, I would suggest doing it the easy way. insert this meta tag in the head element in HTML

```
    <meta name='viewport' content='target-densitydpi=device-dpi,initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,user-scalable=yes'/>
```

you can modify the value of minimum-scale to suit your needs.