# Android: Limiting Zoom Out in Webview

Tags: android, webview, zooming, limit

I have to display an area map in my application. This map is provided as a large jpg file (>1000px * 1000 px). I display it in a webview and I also use the build in zoom controls and the zoompicker, which works pretty well. Now I want to limit the zoom, so that the image can't be smaller than the listview height. Because when I zoom out, and the image gets smaller, a white area is display underneath the webview and this is whatI want to avoid.

Regards, Hof

Comment: similar question [Android webview only zoom in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602191/android-webview-only-zoom-in)

Answer (score 4):

Insert this meta tag in the head element:

```
<meta name='viewport' content='target-densitydpi=device-dpi,initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,user-scalable=yes'/>
```